# Wired Connection icon in the top bar shows often the "Questionmark"

Tags: networking, icons

Ubuntu 20.04 on 2 Systems.
Since approximately 2 weeks, the wired connection icon shows a "Question mark" sometimes on both systems.
I "ignore" it, initiate a network transmission (e.g. DLNA or file transmission PC to PC, Internet access without problems) and the status indication will be changed to "connected" (and vice versa).

As written here https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/status-icons.html.en :

"Connected to a wired network, but there is no route to the internet. This could be due to a misconfiguration of your network, or it could be due to an outage with your internet service provider."

Neither I did change the configuration on both systems, nor I have problems with the Internet or Home-Network connection (checked during "Question mark status").

But it seems it is a misconfiguration. Have someone an idea how to solve the "problem" ?

Comment: Probably something at your router. Try rebooting it before anything else.

Comment: Now I did, startup as described by the manufacturer. Power off, removed all cables. After 1 minute Power On, wait for green power LED not blinking anymore, connect DSL, wait for DSL + Internet+ Tel. green Led not blinking, connect Tel. and after all connect the Network. I think I must wait a few days, whether the problem is solved, thank you for reply.

Comment: Obviously not, again the "Question mark" for approximately 1min, but miniDLNA works without problems, I can see the film without interruptions.

Comment: No, until 2 weeks ago, I could trust the icon indication. If there was something else then the "connected" status, then I had a problem (e.g.: no update of an internet page, also it was indicated by the Icon). Not very often, perhaps less then 3 times per year. But now I have > 20 times per day the "Question mark" indication. Now I did test it again, on the second PC, play an internet film online and send a file to the first PC (2,5GB) without problems, and the "Question mark" will be seen during this time. I did check the transmitted file (a film) : It can be played without problems.

Comment: I agree, something changed recently. I've started having the same issue, with approximately the same timing.

Comment: I did set " Connectivity Checking" to Off, since 1 day no "Question mark" anymore (what else).